# On the choice of general Lyapunov functions for discontinuous control

Tags: control-theory, continuity, lyapunov-functions

Let us consider the following dynamical system:
$$ \dot{X} = A\cdot X + B\cdot u$$ where $X,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. The considered system is linear, but I think that $A\cdot X$ can be eventually replaced with $f(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. I try to define some Lyapunov candidate functions for the general case. However some mistake must be made because I obtain a discontinuous control law able to stabilize some systems which I know are NOT stabilizable. However, below is the reasoning:

### Problem description

Let $$P_+(X) = (X+B)^T (X+B)\cdot 1_{n\times n} + (X+B) (X+B)^T$$ and $$ P_-(X) = (X-B)^T (X-B)\cdot 1_{n\times n} + (X-B) (X-B)^T $$ Then $P_+(X)$, for $X\neq -B$, is a real symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\{2\cdot \|X+B\|^2, \|x+B\|^2,..., \|X+B\|^2\}$ hence $P_+$ is positively defined. Also $P_-(X)$ for $X\neq B$ is a positively defined matrix.

Define the following Lyapunov candidate function:
$$V(X) = \begin{cases}V_1(X) = X^T\cdot P_+(X)\cdot X, \hspace{0.5cm} X^T
\cdot B \geq 0\\ V_2(X) = X^T\cdot P_-(X)\cdot X, \hspace{0.5cm} X^T
\cdot B < 0 \end{cases}$$ Then $V(X) > 0$ for all $X \neq 0$.

Furthermore $V_1(X)\biggr\rvert_{X^T\cdot B = 0} = \|X\|^2(\|X\|^2+\|B\|^2) + \|X\|^4 = V_2(X)\biggr\rvert_{X^T\cdot B = 0}$ hence $V(X)$ is continuous.

Evaluating the derivative of $V$ one obtains:
$$\dot{V}(X) = \begin{cases} 2\cdot X^T\cdot P_+(X)\cdot \left( AX+Bu\right) + X^T\cdot \dot{P}_+(X) \cdot X \hspace{0.5cm} X^T\cdot B \geq 0\\ 2\cdot X^T\cdot P_-(X)\cdot \left( AX+Bu\right) + X^T\cdot \dot{P}_-(X) \cdot X \hspace{0.5cm} X^T\cdot B< 0\end{cases}$$ where let
$$ F_1 = X^T\cdot P_+(X)\cdot B = X^T B \cdot (\|X+B\|^2 + \|X\|^2 + \|B\|^2) + (X^T B)^2 + \|X\|^2\|B\|^2$$ then

$$ F_2 = X^T\cdot P_-(X)\cdot B = X^T B \cdot (\|X-B\|^2 + \|X\|^2 + \|B\|^2) - (X^T B)^2 - \|X\|^2\|B\|^2$$ Also let

$$ E_1 = X^T\cdot P_+(X)\cdot AX \hspace{0.5cm} E_2 = X^T\cdot P_-(X)\cdot AX$$

Finally 
$$X^T\cdot \dot{P}_+(X) \cdot X = X^T\cdot \left( 2(X+B)^T\cdot (AX+Bu) 1_{n\times n} + (AX+Bu)(X+B)^T + (X+B)(AX+Bu)^T\right) \cdot X $$ hence let 
$$ G_1 = ... \hspace{0.5cm} H_1 = 2\cdot X^TB \cdot (\|B\|^2+\|X\|^2 ) + 2\cdot \|B\|^2\|X\|^2 + 2\cdot (B^TX)^2$$ and $G_2$ and $H_2$ are obtained in a similar fashion for $\dot{P}_-(X)$. 
$$ G_2 = ... \hspace{0.5cm} H_2 = 2\cdot X^TB \cdot (\|B\|^2+\|X\|^2 ) - 2\cdot \|B\|^2\|X\|^2 - 2\cdot (B^TX)^2$$

Follows:
$$\dot{V}(X) = \begin{cases}2\cdot E_1(X) + G_1(X) + (2F_1 + H_1)\cdot u \hspace{0.5cm} X^TB \geq 0\\ 2\cdot E_2(X) + G_2(X) + (2F_2 + H_2)\cdot u \hspace{0.5cm} X^TB < 0 \end{cases}$$

### Control law

Let 
$$u(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{-V_1(X) - 2\cdot E_1(X) - G_1(X)}{2\cdot F_1(X) + H_1(X)} \hspace{0.5cm} &x^T\cdot B \geq 0\\ \frac{-V_2(X) - 2\cdot E_2(X) - G_2(X)}{2\cdot F_2(X) + H_2(x)} \hspace{0.5cm} & x^T\cdot B < 0 \\ \end{cases}$$

In this way one obtains
$$ \begin{cases}
\dot{V}_1(X) + V_1(X) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} &X^T\cdot B \geq 0\\
\dot{V}_2(X) + V_2(X) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} &X^T\cdot B < 0
\end{cases} $$ which means $V_1 \to 0$ and $V_2 \to 0$ right? What am I doing wrong? I obtain a stabilization law for ... every system with $B \neq 0$? This is obviously wrong ... but I do not know where is the mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your attention sir! As you can see $2F_2 + H_2 < 0$ for all $X^T\cdot B < 0$ and $2F_1 + H_1 > 0$ for all $X^T\cdot B \geq 0$ except for $X = 0$

Comment: Your expressions for $G_1(X)$ and $G_2(X)$ are missing. I also got a different results, namely $H_1 = 2(x^\top A^\top (x + B) \|x\|^2 + x^\top A\,x\,(x + B)^\top x)$ and  $H_2 = 2(x^\top A^\top (x - B) \|x\|^2 + x^\top A\,x\,(x - B)^\top x)$. But even if these results are the correct ones I still think that the rest of the question seems to hold.

Comment: @Kwin $H_1$ and $H_2$ are some functions of $X$ that multiply the input $u$ and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are some functions such that $X^T\dot{P}_+(X)\cdot X = G_1(X) + H_1(X)\cdot u$ and similarly for $G_2, H_2$. Is this what you have considered? In my count, no coefficient of $u$ has $A$ in it ...

Comment: You are right. I switched my results of $H$ and $G$. So I have $H_1 = 2(B^\top (x + B) \|x\|^2 + x^\top B\,(x + B)^\top x)$ and  $H_2 = 2(B^\top (x - B) \|x\|^2 + x^\top B\,(x - B)^\top x)$.

Comment: Probably if you expand them they get the same shape as mine. I expressed them in this form to show that $H_1 > \|X\|^2 \cdot \|B\|^2$ for $X^TB > 0$ and similar for $H_2 < -\|X\|^2\cdot \|B\|^2$ for $X^T\cdot B < 0$. That is to show that we are not dividing by $0$

Comment: I did not read the details of your derivation but the final logical step is not obvious at all and maybe the point where your reasoning fails. Have you heard of switching systems? Do you know that you may have 2 stable systems $\dot{x}=A_1x$, $\dot{x}=A_2x$ but a switched system that alternates its dynamics between the 2 subsystems can be unstable? Similarly, if $V_1,V_2$ are exponentially decreasing when activated this does not mean that they also tend to zero.

Comment: @RTJ Thank you for your attention! Yes, I've heard of switching systems ... This seems indeed to be the problem However, in this case, the function $V$ is continuous on the switching surface ...

Comment: You are right. If $V$ is continous as it seems to be by definition of $P_+$, $P_-$ then $V$ does go to zero exponentially. What I have also observed now is that $P_+$, $P_-$ are not positive definite. Note that their rank is at most 2 so if n>2 stabilization cannot be proved only convergence towards the surface defined by $V=0$.

Comment: @RTJ $P_+$ and $P_-$ are real symmetric matrices with all eigenvalues greater than $0$ for $X \neq -B$ respectively $X\neq B$, so I think $V$, as it is defined, is greater than $0$ for all $X \neq 0$

Comment: Note that there are $n-2$ independent vectors which if they multiply $P_+$ the result is zero. They only have to be normal to $[1,1,...,1]^T$ and $X+B$. It has to do with the eigenvalue multiplicity and the number of independent eigenvectors. However, after carrying out the calculations to see the $V=0$ surface form one can prove that combined with the 2 inequality conditions ($B^TX\geq 0$) the only solution to $V=0$ is $X=0$. Maybe your input explodes at $X=0$?

Comment: right now I do not have a proof, that at $x=0$ the input does not 'explode' to infinity.